# Javascript Auto Sum dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript

I am creating a quote/order page that includes different types of options for the order all of which are calculated differently. I have a javascript function that will take the values inputed into the text boxes onchange and add a total at the bottom of a page. The issue I'm running into is the base product can be multiple lengths and many option prices are calculated by the foot. So what I have done is made a hidden field that stores the length of the base product and drop down menus to select the option. I have another javascript function that multiplies these two values and puts the total in one of the text boxes that should be auto summed with the first function. Both work perfectly independent of each other, however the issue I have is that the "on change command for the sum function isn't being recognized when the multiplication function auto updates the text box...

Any Help is very greatly appreciated.

Code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function multiplyLengthWalls(){
var length = parseInt(document.getElementById('length').value, 10);
var walls = parseInt(document.getElementById('walls').value, 10);
var total = length*walls;

document.getElementById('wallstotal').value = total;
}


</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function sumCost() {
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('featuretotal');
        var tot = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('totalcost').value = tot;

    }
</script>
```

HTML....

```
<td><select name="walls" id="walls" onchange="multiplyLengthWalls()">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_walls['dcost']?>"><?php echo $row_walls['name']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_walls = mysql_fetch_assoc($walls));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($walls);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($walls, 0);
      $row_walls = mysql_fetch_assoc($walls);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
          <td><label for="wallstotal"></label>
          <input type="text" name="featuretotal" id="wallstotal" class="test" onchange="sumCost()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ceiling:</td>
          <td><label for="ceiling"></label>
            <select name="ceiling" id="ceiling">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_ceiling['dcost']?>"><?php echo $row_ceiling['name']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_ceiling = mysql_fetch_assoc($ceiling));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($ceiling);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($ceiling, 0);
      $row_ceiling = mysql_fetch_assoc($ceiling);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
          <td><label for="ceilingtotal"></label>
          <input type="text" name="featuretotal" id="ceilingtotal" class="test" onchange="sumCost()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Floor:</td>
          <td><label for="floor"></label>
            <select name="floor" id="floor">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_floor['dcost']?>"><?php echo $row_floor['name']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_floor = mysql_fetch_assoc($floor));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($floor);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($floor, 0);
      $row_floor = mysql_fetch_assoc($floor);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
          <td><label for="floortotal"></label>
          <input type="text" name="featuretotal" id="floortotal" class="test" onchange="sumCost()"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

    <div id="structural">structural</div>

    <div id="hidden">hidden -- 
      <input name="length" type="hidden" id="length" value="<?php echo $row_models['length']; ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">

    <div id="total">total:<input name="totalcost" type="text" id="totalcost" readonly="readonly" /></div>
```

Comment: I'll revoke my close vote when I see some code

Comment: There are a number of useful sandbox sites to help you share sample code: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**, **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)**, **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/)**, and **[Plunkr](http://codepen.io/)**, among others.  But you should also post some code here for us to read.

Comment: The PHP code is not much help for a Javascript solution.  You really need to post the output of interpreting the PHP if you're looking for help with JS.